# Stockholm: to Arlanda on an SL card

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, stockholm

I'm in Stockholm, and in a few days I'll have to travel to the Arlanda Airport.

My question is the following: I have some balance on my SL card. The SL site mentions a specific ticket for the airport (at least I need a zone C, and also the airport fee); when I travel to the airport, I will have to take the bus, and then the train to Arlanda. When I first scan the card at the bus, will I have to pay another SEK 25 on top of the train's cost? And when I take the train, how do I indicate that I'm travelling to zone C?

Comment: If you take the Arlanda Express from T-Centralen, it is a direct one as far as I remember so you won't need to indicate anything :)

Comment: True. It is also the fastest way to get from Centralen to Arlanda. But it is not part of the normal commuter system and will draw you back some 280 SEK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A <del>three zone</del> ticket will take you from anywhere in Stockholm all the way to Arlanda including any bus or other railbound transport you want to use.

If you arrive at Arlanda *by SL train* you also need to pay 120 SEK (€12) for entry to the airport (free for under 18s). You can either do this in any Access automat, at the train station before starting your journey or when leaving the train station at Arlanda. At Arlanda you may have to wait for one or two to do this before it is your turn.

If you are on a low budget there is also the option to take the train to Märsta instead and get a number 583 bus from there. This adds about 15 minutes to the journey time. For some reason it is free to access the airport in this way!

Comment: For future readers: zones have been abolished and there's now just a flat fare

Comment: Although there aren't zones any longer, the 120 SEK supplement for traveling to and from Arlanda still exists. https://sl.se/en/eng-info/fares/arlanda/

Comment: I‘ve taken the Märsta route and it was pretty straightforward. The bus is easy to find.