# How do fares to Uppsala and Arlanda Airport work if you are using an unlimited SL Travelcard?

Tags: public-transport, stockholm

We are planning on going to Stockholm via Arlanda Airport (and later Uppsala for a day trip). [Stockholm: to Arlanda on an SL card](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64825/stockholm-to-arlanda-on-an-sl-card) had information on how to travel in general, but I'd like to ask specifically with regards to the unlimited day passes (24/72 hours - https://sl.se/en/in-english/fares--tickets/visitor-tickets/travelcards/).

Our plan is to use these travel cards for our local transportation within Stockholm County, but when we arrive (and when we visit Uppsala), my understanding is that there is an additional fee - for Arlanda, charged by the airport railway operator, and for Uppsala, UL.

Do we need to add a fixed amount of cash balance to the SL card to cover the fee? Does the unlimited rides even work (e.g. will a day pass be rejected entirely and will we be prompted to pay the full ride via a separate ticket instead of just the difference)?

It doesn't matter too much regardless (it will be cheaper than the Arlanda Express) but finding this specific information has proven to be a hassle. Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need tickets that covers your full journey. If you want to travel between Stockholm and Uppsala you need both an SL ticket and a UL ticket. If you combine an unlimited SL ticket with a single ride UL ticket you won't have unlimited trips in the UL area.

When going to Uppsala UL claims that SL sells the UL ticket at manned gates. SL doesn't mention it themselves though. Both the SL app and the UL app also sells the UL ticket (you need UL zone 1,2 and 5). In the UL app there is also a 24h ticket that could be useful.

The airport fee is only paid when departing or arriving at the airport. A ticket for the fee can be bought at the gate at the airport (also when you arrive). It is also sold at manned SL gates and in the SL and UL apps.

Comment: Thanks! So in short, the unlimited SL pass works; you just need to pay the additional fee at arrival/departure from the station, and for Uppsala the portion from the county border to Uppsala requires a separate ticket but the Stockholm portion is fine with the pass?

Comment: @AndrewFan Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to the good answer by Anders that it is possible to go by commuter train and bus to Arlanda to avoid paying the feed. It takes longer but may be an option if you are on a budget. The fee is only when using direct commuter trains to and from Arlanda. The alternate route uses commuter train to Märsta and then bus to Arlanda from there.